# Spring data - Concurrent create-if-not-exists leads to duplicate entires

Tags: java, jpa, concurrency, spring-data

I have the following code, that is run in multiple threads:

```
@Component
public class CreateInstrumentTask {

   @Autowired
   InstrumentRepository repository; // Spring-data JPA repo interface

   @Transactional
   public void createInstrument(String instrumentId) {
      synchronized(instrumentId.intern()) {
         QInstrument $instrument = QInstrument.instrument;
         Instrument instrument = repository.findOne($instrument.instrumentId.eq(instrumentId));

         if (instrument == null) {
            log.info("Thread {} creating instrument {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), message.getInstrumentId());

            instrument = createInstrument(instrumentId); // impl. ommitted
            repository.saveAndFlush(instrument);
         }
      }
   }
```

This logs out:

```
INFO [] Thread taskExecutor-1 creating instrument ABC
INFO [] Thread taskExecutor-17 creating instrument ABC
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException:       
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry 'ABC' for key 'instrumentId';
```

I expected that, given the code is `synchronized` against the `instrumentId`, that duplicates should be prevented.

However, I guess that because the code is transactional, and the boundaries of the transaction are at the method, (not the synchronized block), that the lock is released before the transaction has persisted, allowing the duplicates.

This must be a fairly common pattern ("create-if-not-exists").  What is the correct recipe for performing this in a concurrent fashion?

Comment: Not sure synchronizing is a good idea on that one as it essentially serializes access to this method which limits throughput and subverts the idea of multi-threading access to it in the first place. Have you thought about catching the exception and handling the update case in it?

Comment: @OliverGierke That's a fantastic idea -- I hadn't considered it, no.  The serialization of the processing is palatable, as the majority of the updates are for different instruments, so the code doesn't lock.  However, I'll try swapping across to your approach.  Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up refactoring the method to shift the transactional boundaries:

```
public void createInstrument(String instrumentId) {
   synchronized(instrumentId.intern()) {
        persistInstrument(instrumentId);
   }
}

@Transactional
protected void persistInstrument(String instrumentId) {
    QInstrument $instrument = QInstrument.instrument;
   Instrument instrument = repository.findOne($instrument.instrumentId.eq(instrumentId));

   if (instrument == null) {
      log.info("Thread {} creating instrument {}", Thread.currentThread().getName(), message.getInstrumentId());

      instrument = createInstrument(instrumentId); // impl. ommitted
      repository.saveAndFlush(instrument);
   }   
}
```